# Inserting content into a specific transcluded element (Angular)

Tags: jquery, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am trying to create a directive to create multiple choice activies.
The idea is that in my scope I have a model with an array of questions as such:

```
function Ctrl2($scope) {
  $scope.activity1 = {
      "questions": [
          {
              "question": "This is the first question",
              "answers": ["answer1", "answer2"]
          },
          {
              "question": "When was the American revolution?",
              "answers": [1776, 1881, 1778]
          }
      ]
  };
}
```

I have a directive which finds the questions from the scope and then appends it to the directive element. Here is my directive (simplified for clarity)

```
.directive('multipleChoice', function(){
    return{
        templateUrl: "<div class='ng-transclude'></div>",
        scope: {
            activity:'='
        },
        replace: true,
        transclude: true,
        link: function(scope, element, attrs){
            for (var i=0;i<scope.activity.questions.length;i++){
                var question=scope.activity.questions[i];
               element.append(question.question);
            }
            element.append("<button ng-submit='submit()'>Submit</button><button>Show Solutions</button>")
        }
    }
})
```

However, sometimes I want to insert HTML content between the questions. The way I envisioned doing it something like this.
In my HTML

```
  <div multiple-choice activity="activity1">
      <div id="question1"></div>
      <img src=question2.jpg/>
  </div>
```

and then im my directive instead of appending it to the directive element, appending it to the element with id="question1".

I know an easy solution would be to use JQuery with:
1- rework question model to:

```
{
  "question": "This is the first question",
  "answers": ["answer1", "answer2"],
  "ctn": "#question1"
}
```

and then in my directive doing

```
if (question.ctn!==undefined){
   $(ctn).append(question.question);
}
else{
   element.append(question.question)
}
```

However, I want to stay away from JQuery and try to the "Angular Way".

Another solution I can think of would be to have something like this in my HTML:

```
  <div multiple-choice activity="activity1">
      <div>{{activity.questions.question[0]}}</div>
      <img src=question2.jpg/>
  </div>
```

However, I'm not sure how that would work.

What do you think? Do I have to use jQuery or is there a better way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe it is bad practice to do this and goes against Angular's philisophy. You should try to stay away from jQuery-like content insertion as much as possible.